# Empty result when using MeasurementFormatter with certain pressure values

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

When typing the following code:

```
let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
let measurement = Measurement(value: 1000, unit: UnitPressure.bars)
formatter.string(from: measurement)
```

I'm getting an empty string back. This is happening with some of the UnitPressure values, but works fine with others: i.e `UnitPressure.poundsForcePerSquareInch`.

Is anybody else experiencing this bug? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: That is strange and looks like a bug to me. Interestingly, `millibars` work, so `Measurement(value: bars*1000, unit: UnitPressure.millibars)` would be a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, that'll have to do for now, I've filled a bug report with Apple in the meantime.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. It's working fine for all other dimension but not working for pressure dimension. Have you got any reply for bug report?

Comment: No reply from Apple yet, sorry Yagnesh. I ended up following Martin R's recommendation above in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `unitOptions`:

```
formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
```

With that your sample code produces:

```
1,000 bar
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks, CRD, this does work, however I was hoping to get the localised description for the measurement (which my approach should provide).  I have filed a bug with Apple regarding this.

Comment: @DannyBravo - Setting `unitOptions` doesn't prevent the localisation, however "bar" does not appear to be localised (e.g. ne_NP produces "१,००० bar"). If the unit is millibars then that appears to localised (e.g. ne_NP produces "१,००० मिलिबार"). If you know "bar" should be localised as well as the number then there is indeed another bug (either requiring `.unitOptions`, or not specifying it is required in the docs, is another one).

Comment: Setting it to `.providedUnit` forces the formatter to always display it in the unit you give it, which isn't always the most natural unit for the user's locale. For example, in my app I was hoping it'd display in inches of mercury in the US region, but hectopascals in SI-following regions